# ClearConsole() in C/C++ - function which clears console

Tags: c++, console

I've found a function in C++ which deletes console content. I tested it and it works but I don't understand it. Here is the function:

```
void ClearScreen()
 {
  HANDLE                     hStdOut;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
  DWORD                      count;
  DWORD                      cellCount;
  COORD                      homeCoords = { 0, 0 };
  hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
  if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;
  if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi )) return;
  cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;
  if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
     hStdOut,
     (TCHAR) ' ',
     cellCount,
     homeCoords,
     &count
     )) return;
  if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
     hStdOut,
     csbi.wAttributes,
     cellCount,
     homeCoords,
     &count
     )) return;
  SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdOut, homeCoords );
 }
```

This function uses

```
#include <windows.h>
```

If anyone can explain it to me, how it works, if it is efficient and feel free to suggest me other ways to do the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: If you just want to clear the command window then you can use the [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) method passing the correct clear command. On Windows the clear command is `cls`. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682022(v=vs.85).aspx) out for code examples with comments.

Comment: If you have working code please ask for reviews on SE Code Review.

Answer (score 1):

`system("cls");` is way better I suppose.

Your function gets standard output handle from console (talk to Microsoft)

```
hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ); // info stays in hStdOut (HANDLE)
```

And console buffer information (also, talk to Microsoft)

```
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi ) // info stays in csbi (CON._SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO)
```

Then, fills current console contents with `' '` character (space)

```
FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdOut, (TCHAR) ' ', cellCount, homeCoords, &count) 
                                                           //count is amount of ' ' filled
```

Resets console attributes:

```
FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hStdOut, csbi.wAttributes, cellCount, homeCoords, &count)
// takes info from hStdOut and csbi (cellCount based on csbi), homeCoords is simply {0,0}
```

And rewinds cursor to beginning of console buffer.

```
SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, homeCoords );  // sets cursor to {0,0} coords
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try system("cls") to see how it works. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the console with the windows API involves 3 major steps:

1. Replacing all the text on the screen with a "clear" character (ie. a space)
2. Replacing all the character attributes (foreground/background color) with the console attributes (think of this as the currently selected color in a paint program, although it is set for the whole program, we still need to paint over everything)
3. Move the cursor back to the top-left corner

Respectively achieved with:

- `FillConsoleOutputCharacter()`
- `FillConsoleOutputAttribute()`
- `SetConsoleCursorPosition()`

Of course, we still have to deal with errors and function signatures, but that's the high-level summary.

On a line-by-line basis (after some slight reformatting):

```c
void clearScreen() {
    HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // Get an indentifier (handle) for stdout / the console it's bound to
    if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return; // Return early if there are any errors (indicated by a specific invalid handle value)
    
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi )) return; // Get some information such as the size (`csbi.dwSize`) and attributes (color) (`csbi.wAttributes`) of the console. Also, return early if there is an error (indicated by a return value of 0)
    
    DWORD cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y; // Total number of cells in the console is width*height
    COORD topLeftCorner = {0, 0};
    DWORD count;
    
    if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter( // Step 1: Fill all the character cells with spaces
        hStdOut,
        (TCHAR) ' ', // Fill the console with `cellCount` spaces
        cellCount,
        topLeftCorner, // Starting in the top left corner
        &count // `count` will store the number of characters that were filled. If there is an error, this can be used to determine how many weren't, but the way this function is structured means we have to throw it away.
    )) return; // Return early if there is an error
    
    if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute( // Step 2: Set the cell colors to the console colors
        hStdOut,
        csbi.wAttributes, // Again, think of this as the currently selected color in a paint program. We still need to paint over everything.
        cellCount,
        topLeftCorner,
        &count // Same thing as with `FillConsoleOutputCharacter`
    )) return; // Return early if there is an error
    
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOut, topLeftCorner); // Step 3: Move the cursor back to the top left corner. No need to return early if there is an error since this is the last function call.
}
```

On a side note, this could probably be refactored a bit to

1. Avoid Re-Retrieving the handle for stdout each time (make it a parameter)
2. Avoid Throwing away the `count` after an error (also make it a parameter)
3. Return (or throw) more helpful errors. At this point, there is no programmatic way to tell if the function succeeded, let alone how it failed.

For reference:

- https://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/#Windows (Looks to be the origin of your code snippet)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputcharacter
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/fillconsoleoutputattribute
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition